# Move a question about hyphens and dashes from graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, questions

Few days ago I asked a question whether to use the hyphen or the en dash in cases like *Anglo-Saxon England* and *The Washington–Moscow hotline* on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/143547/whether-to-choose-the-hyphen-or-the-en-dash-in-cases-like-anglo-saxon-england

I had wrongly supposed that this question is related to typography but thanks to Billy Kerr who answered it, it is now obvious that it is actually about English.

Isn't it better to move it to https://english.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be on-topic, but it would be closed as a duplicate of [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

*Anglo-Saxon* is a hyphenated compound; *Washington–Moscow* indicates two ends of a connection. Those instances are similar enough to what's in the existing question to answer yours.

*NB:* This isn't intended to be dismissive of your question! Indeed, it's already been asked and it would be on-topic on ELU if it is not on-topic on GD.SE. You can certainly ask the moderators there to migrate it here, and linking it to a prior question would not reject that migration.

Comment: So may I ask you to move it? :)

Comment: Moderators can't "claim" questions from other sites. If you want it moved, you need to ask GD mods to do that, either in chat or by raising a flag on your question. However, since it is on-topic where it is, they may not acquiesce.